CrowCPP refusing to compile when enabling SSL
I'm having this really weird issue where when I try to compile my Crow project, which I just added SSL support to, it just straight up rejects to compile. This only happens when I add SSL support, works perfectly fine when I try to do without
Note: Yes, I have installed the necessary libraries
Error
https://pastebin.com/PdY2yDfR
Code
https://pastebin.com/AV2Mx4wU
File structure of the project
├── a.out
├── cert.crt
├── cert.key
├── include
├── main.cpp
├── static
├── templates
└── Makefile

Makefile
@all:
    @g++ -o server.bin  *.cpp -DCROW_ENABLE_SSL

I tried to install the necessary libraries(which were already installed, LMDE user here), I tried changing the other of the method chain, nothing. I tried also changing the order of the makefile, where the wiki suggests you to put the compiler definition(If you read the makefile, you saw that didn't work).

Please [edit] your question and include source code (ideally formatted) rather than using links to a 3'rd party resource

You requested to use SSL library without actually linking it to your program. The documentation states it explicitly that -lssl flag is required:

-DCROW_ENABLE_SSL -lssl for HTTPS support

